# Python - знак процента

Tags: python

как называется подобная запись, вывода информации:

```
print("Hello, %s" % foo)
```

и:

```
print("Float - %.2f" % bar)
```

Comment: это [форматирование строк](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это называется [форматирование строк в стиле printf](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting).

Любая строка может включать в себя произвольное число особых спецификаторов форматирования, состоящих из маркерного символа(обычно `%`) и набора параметров преобразования, последним из которых всегда указывается тип форматирования объекта.

Изначально это пошло из стандартной библиотеки языка C, где есть функция `printf()`, принимающая строку с спецификаторами форматирования первым аргументом, а последующими аргументами ей передаются значения произвольного типа. В качестве вывода, эта функция формирует строку с отформатированными в соответствии со спецификаторами значениями, подставленными на место этих самых спецификаторов.

Pyhon вместо этой функции использует оператор форматирования, тоже обозначенный символом процента(`%`) - он разделяет форматную строку и значения, которые с её помощью нужно отформатировать.

Разбирая ваши примеры:

```
"Hello, %s" % foo
```

Означает: отформатировать значение переменной `foo` как строку и вставить её в указанное место.

```
"Float - %.2f" % bar
```

Здесь же `%.2f`требует форматирования `bar` как число с плавающей точкой(f - float), c округлением до 2-х знаков после запятой

Comment: Это не оператор форматирования, а оператор остатка от деления, зачем-то использованный для форматирования строк. Он считается устаревшим (в третьем питоне его вернули только ради обратной совместимости), и вместо него следует использовать функцию format

Comment: @andreymal, конкретно в питоне, если слева от оператора % строит строка, то называется он string formatting operator - оператор форматирования строк. Да, существует и modulus operator(тот самый "оператор остатка от деления"), выглядящий абсолютно так же, но применяющийся когда слева от него стоят значения цифровых типов. Тем не менее, эти операторы независимы друг от друга.

Comment: @andreymal, по поводу "он считается устаревшим" - слухи об этом пошли скорей всего из "хотелок", высказанных в блогах некоторых программистов использующих этот язык. Однако в текущей версии 3-й ветки Python он вовсе не помечен как "deprecated", и разработчики не высказывали желания когда-либо убрать его из спецификации языка.

Comment: С точки зрения питонового кода это один и тот же оператор. И у чисел, и у строк % реализован через магический метод `__mod__` (который по желанию можно перегрузить)

Comment: Мало того, что форматирование при помощи `%` не является устаревшим, так оно ещё и быстрее, чем с использованием `format`: [The relative speeds of str.format and %](http://blog.lerner.co.il/relative-speeds-str-format/)

Comment: А ещё в Python 3.5 появилась поддержка форматирования в бинарных данных: [PEP 461 - % formatting support for bytes and bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-461)

Answer (score 4):

Как уже сказано, `%` - это символ форматирования строк.

Т.е используя процент в строке, мы указываем, что в конечном отображении строки будет использован один из аргументов метода `printf()`. Не стоит забывать, что в строке форматирования после процента мы указываем еще и тип аргумента, который будет выведен в консоль.

```
%s - строка
%f - вещественный
%d - целый
```