# Почему не записывается в файл рандомное значение?

Tags: python-3.x

```
scorematch_A = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
import random
random.shuffle(scorematch_A)
current = scorematch_A.pop()

score = current
print('Результат матча: %d ' %score )

com1 = open('text.txt', 'w')
text.write('%d', %current )
```

Comment: Можно `score = random.choose(scorematch_A)` вместо `shuffle()`+`.pop()` использовать

Answer (score 3):

1. Вы неправильно используете `%` для передачи значения переменной в функцию.

   Согласно [PEP8](http://pep8.ru/doc/tutorial-3.1/7.html):

   > Для форматирования строк можно использовать и операцию `%`. Она интерпретирует левый операнд как строку форматирования в стиле `sprintf`, которую следует применить к правому операнду, и возвращает строку, получившуюся в результате этого преобразования.

   Еще подробней про это в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485312/199091) на ruSO.

   В вашем случае правильно будет `print('Результат матча: %d ' % score )` и `text.write('%d' % current )` .
2. А также неправильно записываете данные в файл.Вместо

   ```
   com1 = open('text.txt', 'w')
   text.write('%d', %current )
   ```

   правильно будет:

   ```
   with open('text.txt', 'w') as file:
       file.write('%d' % current )
   ```

Но вообще, как правильно упомянули в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517239/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/517243#comment633517_517243), почитайте еще [руководств](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420126/199091) по Python и побольше тренируйтесь, чтобы понимать, что происходит в коде.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SAMURAI\Desktop\122.py", line 10, in <module>
    text.write('%d' % current )
NameError: name 'text' is not defined

Comment: @ADDOBOSS вы и правда не создали такую переменную.

Comment: Так это же не переменная, а название текстового файла

Comment: @ADDOBOSS тогда вы не понимаете сути программирования и переменных, и остаётся только посоветовать перечитать какой-нибудь учебник по питону. Вы в последней строке программы пытаетесь обратиться именно к переменной text, которую нигде не создали.

Comment: А всё понял. Ошибка была тут
com1 = open('text.txt', 'w')
com1.write('%d' % current )

Comment: Но файл всё равно не сохраняется

Comment: @ADDOBOSS отредактировал свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Заработало!

Comment: @ADDOBOSS Пожалуйста, если ответ решил вашу проблему, то отметьте его правильным.

Comment: Можно ещё использовать `file.write(str(score))` или `print('Результат матча:' , score, file=file)` вместо `'%d' % score`